# How to let embeeded SWF have access to read files in applicationStorageDirectory in AIR for Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I´m working on an AIR app for android that is a kind of a Video Player for corporate TV´s

The app downloads images, videos and SWFs and store them to play when the playlist ask for them.

The SWFs are usually templates where the user can dynamically put images and texts;
All these information is stored in a XML file on the applicationStorageDirectory;

The problem is that I cant open these extra files (XML, images, etc) from the downloaded SWF when they are called; It shows me Sandbox Security Error;

I tried passing the nativePath as flashVArs to the embeeded SWF. In FLash (Testing on windows) it worked, but in android it didn´t;

Does anyone have an idea of how I can make it work?

Comment: Start here:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply a context when you load your swfs.

```
var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
context.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;

var rslLoader:Loader = new Loader();
rslLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, rslLoadedHandler);
rslLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, rslIOErrorHandler, false, 0, true);
rslLoader.load(new URLRequest("myurl"), context);
```

Find out more about LoaderContext class here:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html

I am concerned this may not work for you though because of the this line in the documentation:

> Content in the AIR application security sandbox cannot load content
>   from other sandboxes into its SecurityDomain.

Try it though, and make sure you let everyone here know the results for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do IT;

I put the files in desktopDirectory instead of applicationStorageDirectory;

With that, my SWF has permissions to access them.

Comment: You want this to work for Android and you put them into `desktopDirectory`, so it worked out?! Are you sure?!